# Visualising amount of similar elements in database in d3.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, d3.js

I created a webcrawler which crawls a website and stores the data into mysql. Next, I would like to visualise the amount of the single response codes of the crawled websites using a pie chart. I decided to use d3.js but I don't know how to visualise the total values of the response codes. For example if I have the following data stored in a json file:

```
    {"crawl":[
{"url":"http:/www.example.com", "responseCode":"200"},
{"url":"http:/www.example.com/page1", "responseCode":"200"},
{"url":"http:/www.example.com/page2", "responseCode":"301"}
{"url":"http:/www.example.com/page3", "responseCode":"200"},
{"url":"http:/www.example.com/page4", "responseCode":"404"},
]}
```

is it possible to visualise how many websites returned a 200, how many returned 301 etc.? So in this case I would like to create a pie chart with the values

```
200 = 3
301 = 1
404 = 1
```

Is this possible without having the absolute values?

Comment: Probably need more information: eg: What are you using in your backend to call mysql? What are you using in the front end? If it's restful to something like Angular, whatever is creating the Apis should be aggregating these counts before sending to the client.

Comment: You can use `d3.nest()`, see e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/).

Comment: Thank you very much @LarsKotthoff! That's exactly what I've been looking for. I guess d3.nest together with d3.rollup will do the job just fine!